# How to use "::" as the prefix for a snippet in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to create snippet so that when I hit TAB after entering :: I get the unicode version of the double colon: ∷.

My attempts at escaping with various backslashes `\\:\\:` and `\\\:\\\:` have failed me.

```
{ "Insert double colon": {
    "prefix": "::",
    "body": [ "∷$0" ],
    "description": "Inserts a unicode type annotation sign"
}
```

I expect to be able to hit TAB after :: but it only inserts a few spaces.

Comment: Works fine for me as is.  No slashes.  Just wondering what is the unicode for the double colon?  But your code seems to work.  Do you get the snippet suggestion after you type `::`?

Comment: You might try `"body": ["\u2237$0"],` and see if it works for you too.